# How to preload core data in simulator?

Tags: sqlite, core-data

I try to **add core data's - with data already loaded - sqlite database to the project**. I am running App on **simulator**, on device I get no problem. The goal to preload fresh launching app with data. In the document folder I have 3 database file:**sqlite**, **sqlite-shm**, **sqlite-wal**. I have chosen to **copy to the project only the sqlite** file. When I restarting App with preoloaded database, It **seems that database is empty**. Why? On device there would be only one database file, which would be not corrupted. Database connection was not closed on simulator, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here the answer: [How to preload data into an iOS app using sqlite files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589541/how-to-preload-data-into-an-ios-app-using-sqlite-files?rq=1)

In oder to get core data to behave in the old way (pre-iOS 7), and generate just the sqlite file, I had to add this argument to the ***addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:*** method call, in the options parameter. You can find it in AppDelegate.

```
@{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE" } }
```